# Get img src with beautifulsoup4 is returning an empty array response

Tags: beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-3.8

I'm trying to get the url src from the following html

[image]

For some reason when i try to print out the logo url, I get `[]` as a response. My code is as follows:

```
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'https://growjo.com/industry/Cannabis'
request = Request(
    url,
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
)
page = urlopen(request)
page_content_bytes = page.read()
page_html = page_content_bytes.decode("utf-8")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

company_rows = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"jss31"})[0].find_all("tbody")[0].find_all("tr")

for company in company_rows:
    company_data = company.find_all("td")
    logo = company_data[1].find_all("div",{"class":"lazyload-wrapper"})[0].find_all("a")
    name = company_data[1].text
    print(logo)
    break
```

I tried printing out the 'a' tags...i tried the 'img'...they all respond with `[]`. Its as if bs4 is not reading within the `div class=lazyload-wrapper`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The urls those contain logos are entirely dynamic
2. Bs4 can't render JS
3. API is restricted by authentication
4. Use an automation tool something like seleniun
5. Here I use Selenium4 with bs4
6. WebDriverManager is [here](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

   ```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    import time

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    #chrome to stay open
    #options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
    url= 'https://growjo.com/industry/Cannabis'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

    company_rows = soup.select('table.jss31 tbody tr')

    for company in company_rows:
        log = company.select_one('td[class="jss38 jss40 jss46"] div + a')
        logo = 'https://growjo.com' + log.get('href') if log else None
        print(logo)
   ```

**Output:**

```
https://growjo.com/company/Dutchie
https://growjo.com/company/Ascend_Wellness_Holdings
https://growjo.com/company/Hiku_Brands
https://growjo.com/company/C3_Industries
https://growjo.com/company/Jane_Technologies
https://growjo.com/company/Headset
https://growjo.com/company/Jushi_Holdings
https://growjo.com/company/FLOWER_CO.
https://growjo.com/company/Columbia_Care
https://growjo.com/company/Cannabis_Control_Commission
https://growjo.com/company/FIGR
https://growjo.com/company/Leafly
https://growjo.com/company/Hound_Labs
https://growjo.com/company/Leaf_Trade
https://growjo.com/company/Wurk
https://growjo.com/company/Sundial_Cannabis
https://growjo.com/company/BEYOND_%2F_HELLO
https://growjo.com/company/PharmaCann
https://growjo.com/company/LeafLink
https://growjo.com/company/Connected_Cannabis_Co.
https://growjo.com/company/NATURE'S_MEDICINES
https://growjo.com/company/Althea_Group
https://growjo.com/company/CURE_Pharmaceutical
https://growjo.com/company/urban-gro
https://growjo.com/company/NABIS
None
https://growjo.com/company/Medisun
https://growjo.com/company/Mammoth_Distribution
https://growjo.com/company/Dosecann_Cannabis_Solutions
https://growjo.com/company/Vireo_Health
https://growjo.com/company/Dama_Financial
https://growjo.com/company/Caliber
https://growjo.com/company/springbig
https://growjo.com/company/Westleaf
https://growjo.com/company/INSA
https://growjo.com/company/Pure_Sunfarms
https://growjo.com/company/Sensi_Media_Group
https://growjo.com/company/Verano_Holdings
https://growjo.com/company/TILT_Holdings
https://growjo.com/company/Bloom_Medicinals
https://growjo.com/company/Planet_13_Holdings
https://growjo.com/company/Liberty_Health_Sciences
https://growjo.com/company/Calyx_Peak_Companies
https://growjo.com/company/Vangst
https://growjo.com/company/Fire_&_Flower
https://growjo.com/company/Revolution_Enterprises
https://growjo.com/company/4Front_Ventures
https://growjo.com/company/Calyx_Containers
https://growjo.com/company/GreenTech_Industries
https://growjo.com/company/BZAM_Cannabis
https://growjo.com/company/Cova_Software
None
https://growjo.com/company/Up_Cannabis
https://growjo.com/company/Cann_Group
https://growjo.com/company/Holistic_Industries
https://growjo.com/company/Treez
https://growjo.com/company/INDIVA
https://growjo.com/company/Kiva_Confections
https://growjo.com/company/MariMed
https://growjo.com/company/MCR_Labs
https://growjo.com/company/Vicente_Sederberg
https://growjo.com/company/Demetrix
https://growjo.com/company/365_Cannabis
https://growjo.com/company/LivWell_Enlightened_Health
https://growjo.com/company/High_Tide
https://growjo.com/company/The_Hawthorne_Gardening_Company
https://growjo.com/company/WYLD
https://growjo.com/company/VidaCann
https://growjo.com/company/Sira_Naturals
https://growjo.com/company/iAnthus
https://growjo.com/company/EastHORN_Clinical_Services
https://growjo.com/company/PharmaCielo
https://growjo.com/company/OCS_Ontario_Cannabis_Store
https://growjo.com/company/Hugh_Wood_Canada
https://growjo.com/company/Wana_Brands
https://growjo.com/company/Parallel
https://growjo.com/company/Weedmaps
None
https://growjo.com/company/Dark_Heart_Nursery
https://growjo.com/company/Stealth_Monitoring
https://growjo.com/company/dicentra
https://growjo.com/company/Sunday_Goods_&_The_Pharm
https://growjo.com/company/Phase_Zero_Design
https://growjo.com/company/Sava
https://growjo.com/company/Ceylon_Solutions
https://growjo.com/company/Green_Flower
https://growjo.com/company/Shryne_Group
https://growjo.com/company/MJ_Freeway
https://growjo.com/company/Theory_Wellness
https://growjo.com/company/HEXO_Corp
https://growjo.com/company/Lightshade
https://growjo.com/company/New_Frontier_Data
https://growjo.com/company/Mission_Dispensaries
https://growjo.com/company/FLUENT_Cannabis_Care
https://growjo.com/company/Superette
https://growjo.com/company/HdL_Companies
https://growjo.com/company/Helix_Technologies
https://growjo.com/company/Mary's_Medicinals
https://growjo.com/company/Indus_Holdings
https://growjo.com/company/Auxly
https://growjo.com/company/Good_Chemistry
https://growjo.com/company/Khiron_Life_Sciences_Corp
https://growjo.com/company/The_Apothecarium
```

Comment: Thanks...it sorta works...I can work with it from here though. Is there a way to prevent a new browser window from opening every time i run the program?

Comment: yes, you can use headless mode : options.add_argument("--headless")

Comment: I added it but the browser still opens.

Comment: Uncomment options.add_argument("start-maximized") and see what's happen

Comment: In selenium, there are two options non-headless and headless browser mode and I said both of them

Comment: No change...i'll mark my question as answered and work on it some more later one. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I'm using Firefox btw...not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ok ,MaxxABillion Thank you  too

Comment: Don't worry, both browser  will work